# How to change terminal prompt color to black?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

I want to change the color of my terminal prompt to black color which is now in green color.

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: You probably didn't search a lot before asking here : [BASH Shell: Change The Color of Shell Prompt on Linux or UNIX](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/) [In bash how can I change the color of my command prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16120/in-bash-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-command-prompt)

Comment: is there any software available for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know if there is a software, but you can use generator like this one http://bashrcgenerator.com/

Comment: You can create your prompt on the website, and then you copy the generated line at the end of your ~/.bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

If your term is in an X window, change the line
xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;

to

xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=no;;
in .bashrc